# Ant Build File Configuration

Tags: java, ant

Using Ant to compile simple Hello World program in Java, and something isn't working right. I know the Java code is correct, as it runs using javac. Something is wrong with my Any config file, and I can't quite figure out what it is. http://pastebin.com/q50L5b0D

and the command line errors I'm getting:

```
 **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Proj0/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Proj0.class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: Proj0.class. Program will exit.
**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just tell you the class `Proj0` could not be found when trying to run your application using the `ANT` target you defined. Are you sure this line is correct ?

```
<property name="Proj0.class" value="package.names.Proj0"/>
```

The `package.names.Proj0` is a strange name for a package, maybe you wanted something like using the actual value of a property called `package.names`?

Answer (score 1):

For your `javac` task need to set the `classpath` , `srcdir` properly. As Vincent wrote you are missing the `Proj0` class. Please look [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) for how to set the `javac` task.